# How to add data to JavaFX Table rows/cells

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX table and I want to add some data to each of the rows. The data comes from a text file.
This is the code that is supposed to input each data piece into a specific cell
Each line in the file is in this format:

```
firstName;LastName;SchoolName;email;year;active?;amountOwed;
```

Basically each line is a row in the table.

```
try{
        ArrayList<String> allLinesOfTheFile= new ArrayList<String>();
        String path = "G:\\";
        String line;
        File masterFile = new File(path,"masterfile.txt");
        BufferedReader readMasterFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(masterFile));

        while ((line = readMasterFile.readLine()) != null) {

            for (String data: line.split(";")){

                //this splits the data into individual pieces, each piece will take up one cell in the table

            }

        }


    }
```

[Here is the tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOBLv.jpg)

Comment: So you are asking how to add the values from `data` into a JavaFX table? Did you try anything? The code you show seems to get the data from the file, but did you already set up the JavaFX table? You could start with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

Comment: BTW: `String[]` can be used as item type, but I'd recommend creating a class holding the information.

Comment: I have already set up the table in scenebuilder, and did the whole fxml injection thing, I just need to add values to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a model class to hold the values. Here's an small example you can use

**Model Class:**

```
public class Model {

    private String col1;
    private String col2;

    public Model(String[] st){
        this.col1 = st[0];
        this.col2 = st[1];
    }
    public String getCol1() {
        return col1;
    }

    public void setCol1(String col1) {
        this.col1 = col1;
    }

    public String getCol2() {
        return col2;
    }

    public void setCol2(String col2) {
        this.col2 = col2;
    }

}
```

**Your controller class**

```
  ObservableList<Model> lst = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    String path = "G:\\";
    String line;
    File masterFile = new File(path,"masterfile.txt");
    BufferedReader readMasterFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(masterFile));

    while ((line = readMasterFile.readLine()) != null) {

          String[] data =line.split(";");
          Model md= new Model(data);
          lst.add(md);
   }
   table.setItems(lst);
```

Comment: What type of variable/object is table? I tried this and got multiple errors.

Comment: Also, i get an error when I use setItems, says it needs an arraylist of type string.

Comment: `table` is your  javafx `TableView` on which you want to show the details. How did you make your  `TableView` with all the columns included? You need the mention the model class which is mapped to your table. Then only it will accept the ObservableList of your Model class. Also you might be using `setItems` on a wrong object, because javafx `TableView` accepts only  `ObservableList` as an Item.

Comment: Yes but it says it needs an observableList of sype string

Comment: you might have your `TableView` declared as `TableView<?> tableName`. What is there is place of `?` ?

Comment: think ive got it now.Thanks a lot